# Uploading a file to Google drive using iOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-drive-api

In my current application, I am trying to upload a `.text` file to google drive using `Google SDK for iOS`. But the issue is every time I got the error message in my `Log` as **`Insufficient Permission`**, so If anyone have faced this or have an idea on this type of error kindly help me.

**Here is my code,**

```
        GTLDriveFile *file = [GTLDriveFile object];
        file.descriptionProperty = @"Uploaded from the iOS app.";
        file.mimeType = @"text/*";
        file.name=@"MyTextFile";
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myTestFile" ofType:@"txt"];

        GTLUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [GTLUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath] MIMEType:file.mimeType];


        GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesCreateWithObject:file uploadParameters:uploadParameters];

        [self.service executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            }else{

            }
        }];
```

**Log print when this action is performed,**

***unexpected response data (uploading to the wrong URL?)
{"error":{"code":403,"message":"Insufficient Permission","data":[{"domain":"global","reason":"insufficientPermissions","message":"Insufficient Permission"}]},"id":"gtl_3"}***

***Premature failure: upload-status:"final"  location:(null)***

Comment: Please go through this link https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/quickstart

Comment: Also try this https://developers.google.com/drive/ios/devguide/files

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem

## First Step

**change your scope to `[kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile]`**

but after first step, i got a same 403 error

because my APP in my phone have scope `[kGTLAuthScopeDriveMetadataReadonly]`

## Second Step

**reset my application or build in another simulator**

I think first auth key chain using scope readonly was existed so doesn't write file to google drive

after change scope and re-auth then it works

if you change `kKeychainItemName`'s value to another then could re-auth again with new scope

google says in Quickstart tutorial

```
// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials by
// resetting the iOS simulator or uninstall the app.
// private let scopes = [kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile]
```