# Can I upload files to google drive from iOS Application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, google-drive-api

I'm creating an application that collects data from a bluetooth peripheral. When all of the data is collected I want to upload my data, which is in the format of a `.txt`file, to a google drive account for processing.

I have looked at this method and it doesn't really seem to fit the purpose
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ios?ver=objc

Is there anyway way I can do this in Objective-C? I have searched everywhere and I cannot seem to find something.

Comment: Refer : https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads

Answer (score 2):

An easy way is to leverage the [CloudRail SDK](https://cloudrail.com/integrations/interfaces/CloudStorage;serviceIds=GoogleDrive;interfaceId=CloudStorage;interfaceFunctionId=CloudStorage-upload;platformId=ObjectiveC) for Google Drive. Here is how you would upload a file:

```
CRGoogleDrive * service = [[CRGoogleDrive alloc] initWithClientIdentifier:@"[Google Drive Client Identifier]"
        clientSecret:@"[Google Drive Client Secret]"
        redirectUri:@"http://localhost:12345/auth"
        state:@"someState"
];

[service uploadFileToPath:@"/myFolder/myFile.png" 
        stream:readableStream 
        size:1024 
        overwrite:true
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can upload a text file to google drive. Please look up to this post.
[IOS: How to upload a file to specific Google drive folder using Google drive sdk library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439457/ios-how-to-upload-a-file-to-specific-google-drive-folder-using-google-drive-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can upload .txt and other type of file on google drive. You can go through from this tutorial [Google Drive Integration in iOS apps](https://web.archive.org/web/20161127055330/http://www.innofied.com:80/google-drive-integration-in-ios-apps)  and
[Uploading a file to Google drive using iOS sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629776/uploading-a-file-to-google-drive-using-ios-sdk?rq=1)

Or
Refer [Introduction to the Google APIs Client Library for Objective-C for REST](http://%20http:https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/wiki)for detail explanation.